# OpenRTB bid creative's dimensions

Tags: height, width, response, dimensions, bids

According to OpenRTB spec:

```
bid.h - integer, optional - Height of the creative in pixels.
bid.w - integer, optional - Width of the creative in pixels.
```

Why are these optional? Why would we have to bother sending back the dimensions in the response since we can simply skip those parameters according to the spec?